# Prove that if $n \equiv 7 \pmod 8$, then $n$ cannot be expressed as the sum of three squares.

Tags: number-theory

I begin by contradiction. Assume that $n$ can be expressed as the sum of three squares. That is $n = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$. Now since $n \equiv 7 \pmod 8$ then $8 \mid n - 7$ so $8 \mid a^2 + b^2 + c^2 - 7$. But then I don't know how to proceed from here. Any ideas

Comment: Hint: Find all the values squares can take mod 8. Can any sum of these three be 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the equation modulo $8$ for every integer $x$ we have $x^2\equiv 0,1,4 \mod 8$ $ a^2+b^2+c^2\equiv 7 \mod 8$

Can three numbers from $0,1,4$ sum to $7$?

Comment: $0^2 = 0$, $1^2 = 1,2^2 = 4$ $3^2 = 9 =1,4^2 = 16 = 0,5^2=25=1,6^2=36=2,7^2 =49=1$ mod 8  

mmm Now I see that for all $x$ we do have $x^2 \equiv 0,1,4$ Now how to argue that   any combination of 0 ,1,4 don't sum to 7 ? 

That is 

1m + 4n = 7 is never true for all values of m and n

Comment: you can compute all possible value modulo $8$

Answer (score 0):

This means $n$ is odd. Hence, if $n=a^2+b^2+c^2$, we have two possibilities.

1. All of $a,b,c$ are odd. This means that $a^2\equiv1\pmod8$, $b^2\equiv1\pmod8$ and $c^2\equiv1\pmod8$. Hence,
   $$n = a^2+b^2+c^2 \equiv 3\pmod8 \not\equiv 7\pmod8$$
2. Two of $a,b,c$ are even and other one is odd. Without loss of generality, assume $a,b$ are even and $c$ is odd. This means that $a^2\equiv0\pmod4$, $b^2\equiv0\pmod4$ and $c^2\equiv1\pmod4$. Hence,
   $$n = a^2+b^2+c^2 \equiv 1\pmod4 \not\equiv 7\pmod8$$